# Error displaying a variable from Flask into javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, variables, flask, apostrophe

This is my FLASK variable `{{ list_fruits }}` when I display it between the `<body>` brakets in the browser I get :

```
<body>
{{ list_fruits }}
</body>

[ ['Bananas', 8], ['Kiwi', 3], ['Mixed nuts', 1],['Oranges', 6], ['Apples', 8] ]
```

But when I display it between the javascript `<script>` brackets the `Apostrophes` converts to `&#39;` so I get something like this:

```
<script>
{{ list_fruits }}
</script>


[ [&#39;Bananas&#39;;, 8], [&#39;Kiwi&#39;, 3], [&#39;Mixed nuts&#39;, 1],[&#39;Oranges&#39;, 6], [&#39;Apples&#39;, 8] ]
```

How to prevent javascript from transferring the `Apostrophes` to `&#39;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `{{ list_fruits|tojson|safe }}` to inject JSON data into your template.